# What is the best way to make a read only dependency property in WinRT?

Tags: windows-runtime, dependency-properties

There doesn't appear to be an equivalent of RegisterReadOnly in WinRT.

Is there a good workaround?

How do the controls in WinRT implement thing like ActualWidthProperty?

Answer (score 0):

When implementing dependency property use usually define static property type with metadata and then you create accessible property with getter and setter, so if you want to create readonly property, just create visible property only with getter.

Comment: Would this make it possible for anything to set the property though with the SetProperty method (found on DependencyObjects)?